# Does the localization functor $\mathcal{C}\to S^{-1}\mathcal{C}$ preserve finite colimits when $\mathcal{C}$ is not small? (size issues in proof)

Tags: ct.category-theory, localization

$\def\colim{\operatorname{colim}}
\def\hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $S$ be a class of morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$ that is a [left multiplicative system](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VC). The localization of $\mathcal{C}$ with respect to $S$ is a category $S^{-1}\mathcal{C}$ with same objects as $\mathcal{C}$ and where a morphism $X\to Y$ in $S^{-1}\mathcal{C}$ is a pair of maps $X\xrightarrow{f}Y'\xleftarrow{s}Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$, with $s\in S$, modulo a certain equivalence relation (cf. [04VB](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04VB)).

> **Fact.** $S^{-1}\mathcal{C}$ is not locally small in general (even when $\mathcal{C}$ is) [[ref](https://mathoverflow.net/q/321141/101848)].

The localization $S^{-1}\mathcal{C}$ comes equipped with a canonical localization functor $Q:\mathcal{C}\to S^{-1}\mathcal{C}$. In Gabriel, Zisman, *Calculus of Fractions and Homotopy Theory*, Proposition I.3.1 states that $Q$ preserves finite direct limits. Actually, their proof works for finite colimits, as it is stated and done with the same proof in the Stacks Project [05Q2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05Q2). The proof boils down to noticing
$$
\label{hom_loc}\tag{1}
\operatorname{Hom}_{S^{-1}\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)=\underset{(Y\to Y')\in Y/S}{\colim}\hom_\mathcal{C}(X,Y')
$$
(see [05Q0](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05Q0) for the definition of $Y/S$) and then using that

> $(*)$ finite limits commute with filtered colimits in the category of sets.

Here's the big *but*: in the colimit \eqref{hom_loc} the category $Y/S$ is a not small category in general, so we cannot apply $(*)$ to something that may not be a set! The Stacks Project has a funny way of dealing with this: for them, by default all categories are small (unless one works with certain specific categories) [0013](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0013). So [05Q2](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/05Q2) constitutes a sound proof, for one assumes $\mathcal{C}$ is small. The problem is Gabriel and Zisman's proof: they do it for a possibly non-small category, so I don't see how one can get something meaningful now.

Even though it is not clear in which category the colimit is taken over, formula \eqref{hom_loc} shows up in the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/calculus+of+fractions#construction_of_the_localization) and [Verdier's thesis](http://www.numdam.org/item/AST_1996__239__R1_0.pdf), Corollaire 2.2.4.

Comment: I would say every category of small in a sufficiently large universe, so it works. Size issues are only important when it comes to *relative* sizes.

Comment: @JonasFrey Do you mean "every category *is* small in a sufficiently large universe"? If yes, what is the meaning of these words?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean! It's a foundational principle promoted eg by Grothendieck: categories whose collections of objects are "classes" in the ZF-sense of the world, are very unwieldy, so instead of using them we postulate a Grothendieck universe and say that everything inside the universe is small, and things outside are not (necessarily). This way even the "large" objects are set-sized, and can be manipulated without foundational problems.

Comment: @JonasFrey Thanks for the explanation ^^. Do you know any reference for these ideas?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo Try https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+universe. The assertion (*) is correct in ZFC + enough Grothendieck universes.

Comment: If the comma category is large you can't even ensure that the localisation exists. In specific cases localisations exist for a reason. Maybe, in your case, those reasons ensure that you can replace the comma category with a small cofinal one, so you would be done. Universes are tricky because you're assuming that all categories are small, but you bound sets of objects and morphisms by different inaccessible cardinals, the first one being bigger than the second one. When you localise, the cardinal of morphism sets may jump, entering the exclusion zone.

Comment: @FernandoMuro By "the comma category" do you mean $Y/S$?

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo yes.